# Error creating database with JS, Node and SQlite3

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I just want to start off by saying that I have found out Stack questions that are similar if not the same, but the answers there don't work.

I am just wanting to make a smallish database so I can query all of my items in storage. I thought I would try out SQLite because people say that it is easy to use and lightweight.

Here is the question/answer that doesn't work: [sqlite3 create database with callback using node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51184070/sqlite3-create-database-with-callback-using-node) and here is the reference from [sqlitetutorial.net](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/connect/)

Here is my code and the errors I am getting. I don't understand why it is not just creating a new database.

```js
'use strict'

// Open the database in memory
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

let db = new sqlite3.Database('/db/storage.db', (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    } else {
        console.log('Connected to the in memory SQlite database.')
    }
});


// Close the database
db.close((err) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err.message);
    }
    console.log('Close the database connection.');
});
```

Then the error message is

```
SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Or then if I use the `sqlite3.OPEN_CREATE` parameter, I get this error.

```
SQLITE_MISUSE: bad parameter or other API misuse
Segmentation fault (core dumped) code here
```

So I don't entirely know what's wrong here, as it's just my first hour messing around with it but it seems many others have had this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue and it is a really simple one. It was just me not paying attention to directory locations. When declaring the database the dot NEEDS to be there.

```
let db = new sqlite3.Database('./db/storage.db', (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    } else {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```